# interpreting different cookie types

Tags: post, curl, cookies, httprequest

I've been looking at some login forms lately. I saw how many different type of cookies they use. I've not been able to identify the meaning of them. I get the idea that cookies give information to the server about the current state. But why so many? This is a screenshot from a popular website login post request. As you can see there are many. How do they differ and what information they reveal by inspecting them?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very good at reading cookies, but I think Google thinks you're from Slovenia. ;)

But most of these cookies don't contain much relevant data at all. They're just some id, so the browser knows that the next request is you again. So the string of garbage is just some id, so after you navigate from the login page to another page of the same domain, the server knows that it is still you.

Not all cookies are for the login feature of the site itself, some are for tracking purposes:

- __gads is for Double Click, related to Google advertising.
- __ssid is for SiteSpect, a tool for A/B testing.
- _ga I *think* is for Google Analytics, a tool to gather website statistics.
- and so on.

But still, these cookies normally don't contain user names or passwords or other sensitive information. They are just to 'anonymously' track you. They just gather big data saying that people who visited Page X also visited Page Y, and by that sites like Google generate profiles to show targeted advertising.

Comment: Thank you! Based on your username, you could be my neighbour :D